# Google Sheets: Create button that copies tab to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a button in google sheets that, when clicked, it copies one tab (tab 1) to another (tab 2). I need it to paste Values Only. I also need it to overwrite the data in tab 2 each time it is copied.

I have been searching online and pulling different things together but I haven't been able to get something that works.

All help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried a few scripts I have found online but I haven't been able to put them together to get this to work.

Comment: Hello, in order to help us understand your problem, you will need to add more details to your question like (source code, screenshots)

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming:

1. The dataset is not too large (over 10k rows);
2. No header considered, as it gets the data from row 01

```
function moveData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const tab1 = ss.getSheetByName('tab1');
  const data = tab1.getRange(1,1,tab1.getLastRow(),tab1.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  const tab2 = ss.getSheetByName('tab2')

  tab2.getRange(tab2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].lengt).setValues(data);
}
```

Check this one for creating a custom menu [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

If a button is required, add a drawing in the shape of a button, a text to it and assign moveData as the script to it, once this is on your spreadsheet.

Comment: When I try this it brings back the error:

"Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange."

Comment: @user18625682, just corrected a couple of points. If you haven't solved it yet, you can try it now.

Comment: if there is a header, you can just easily add an offset to data @user18625682

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem statement, you can try below sample script:-

```
function copyData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const tab1 = ss.getSheetByName('tab1');
  const sourceData = tab1.getDataRange().getValues();// getting all the data from tab1    
  const tab2 = ss.getSheetByName('tab2')    
  tab2.getRange(1, 1, sourceData.length, sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData );// pasting all the data in tab2 with header 
}
```

You can add a button through drawing and assign the function `copyData` to it.

**Reference:-**

[getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)